# Literature applying molecular docking into MD-simulated structures of proteins

Tags: molecular-dynamics, reference-request, docking

This is quite surprising, at least for me, that many papers performed molecular docking of an unsimulated (original) protein structure and MD simulation of a protein in a timescale to check the stability of the protein structure but none of them performed molecular docking of a simulated protein structure, let alone the MD of protein-ligand after the docking process from previous simulated one. Is this a novel idea **or some research labs have already made it on this case?**

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been almost 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?